# Random State in random.sample

Tags: python, pandas, random-seed

I was writing code for custom GridSearchCV. I want to select and shuffle indies everytime I execute the code. But I was not able to figure out how to implement seed function into it.
Below is my code snippet. Please let me know if I need to make any additions.

Code:

```
train_indices=random.sample(range(0,len(x_train)),int(folds_percent*len(x_train)))
test_indices=list(set(list(range(1,len(x_train))))-set(train_indices))
```

Thanks for help!|:-)

Comment: it seems like you have to use `random.seed()` to do this. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html.

Answer (score 3):

Before call the `random.sample()` put the `random.seed()` command:

```
random.seed(41)
random.sample([1,2,3,4,5], k=2)
```